# JS/JQUERY: on(scroll) interfering with on(click)

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, in the script of my website, I have functions:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function(){
     // some code
});

$('.subnav_single_box').on('click', function(){
      $('#h1').animate({ right : '300%'}, 1000);  
     // some more code -shall refer to this block of code later
 });
```

The problem is that some_more_code, inside `on(click)` works, but the `#h1`-code works only sometimes.

If I do not scroll before clicking the `.subnav_single_box`, then everything works just as I want it to, but if I scroll before clicking, then "some more code" works, but not `#h1`-code.

How do I fix this?

Comment: So what happens in the scroll code?

Comment: The scroll code has some navigation bar animations. And also some #h1 animations. I am using .css() to tie opacity of that #h1 to scroll position.Also I use .animate() on #h1 to slide it into the screen from left to right on scroll.